# How do I print the highest value in a class?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a class for a game I'm making and I need to print the highest value out of five individuals. How would I do that? for example

```
class villains:
    def __init__(self,health, damage):
        self.health = first_name
        self.damage = damage

v1 = villains(20,15)
v2 = villains(22,12)
```

How would I get it to print the highest value for health instead of just printing the individual values?

Comment: You would need to collect all the values and see which one is highest, then print that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over each villan and check if it's the largest

```
v1 = villains(20,15)
v2 = villains(22,12)

all_villans = [v1, v2]
largest_villan = all_villans[0]
for current_villan in all_villans[1:]:
    if current_villan.health > largest_villan.health:
        largest_villan = current_villan
```